# Update a table step by step based on another table

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Above is a scheme i drew. There's an ideal case, when `content.user` are groupped. But usually they are not groupped.
What i meant in this scheme is:

1. At the first step, i select `users.monetos` WHERE `users.id = content.user`
2. At the second step, i decrement `users.monetos` with every `content.cpc` value (2.1 , 2.2)

When simulating this:
 select `content.user` (9)

select `users.monetos` Where `users.id=content.users` (15)

So we have 15 value for `users.monetos` for `users.id=9`, now we go back to content table
and:

1. decrement 15 value with 8 (`content.cpc`) (15-8=**7** > 0 -> go to step 2)
2. decrement 7 (result from previous step) with 10 (`content.cpc`) (7-10=-3 <0 -> update
   content set active='0' where content.id= (current id when a negative result obtained) )

And like this for every `content.user`

**More extended** - I want to select `contet.*` rows which have `content.active` = 1 **(n)**. Having this data, `SELECT` `users.monetos` WHERE `users.id`=`content.user` from previous query.
And now, by maximum **(n)** steps i decrement `users.monetos` value by **content.cpc** value 
and **on the moment when **users.monetos**=0 or less than 0, i want to update `content` and SET active='0'**

By words, i want like to share **users.monetos** amount to each **content** entry (**content.cpc** for each). And there's no more **users.monetos** make the current `content` 
entry inactive. And do this vor every **content.user**
What i'he done at this moment is shown below. I now it looks really bad, but i already don't know what to do. Count on you guys. Thank you.

```
$query = "select content.id, content.cpc, conent.user, content.active from content a
join users b on a.user=b.id
group by b.id where a.active='1'";

/** cycle each user **/
foreach($rows = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $row ) {
    $monetos = $row['monetos'];
    $query = "select id, cpc from content where user={$row['id']}";
    /** cycle each users content **/
    foreach($contents = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $content) {
        echo $monetos;
        $monetos -= $content['cpc'];
        if($monetos <= 0) {
            $disable[] = $content['id'];
        }
    }
    if( isset($disable) ) {
        $connector->query("update content set active='0' where id in(".implode(',',$disable).")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `GROUP_CONCAT` we group the `ID`s and `CPC`s separated by a comma for later use and with `GROUP BY` the user `ID` we will get a single row of result per user.

On the `foreach` we deduce each `CPC` from the `MONETOS` and from there we set who needs to be disabled to the `$to_disable` array that is later used to disable all the id's needed to.

```
$query = "SELECT b.id AS user_id,
                 b.monetos,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(a.id ORDER BY a.id DESC) AS content_ids, 
                 GROUP_CONCAT(a.cpc ORDER BY a.id DESC) AS cpc,
            FROM content a
            JOIN users b 
              ON a.user = b.id
        GROUP BY b.id";

$to_disable = array();
$to_enable = array();
foreach($rows = $connector->fetchArray($query) as $row)
{
    $monetos = $row['monetos'];
    $data = array_combine(explode(',',$row['content_ids']), explode(',',$row['cpc']));
    echo "USER {$row['user_id']} currently have {$monetos}!<br>\n";
    foreach ($data as $content_id => $cpc)
    {
        $monetos -= $cpc;
        echo "USER {$row['user_id']} after CONTENT {$content_id} now have {$monetos}!<br>\n";
        if ($monetos <= 0)
        {
            echo "USER {$row['user_id']} should have the CONTENT {$content_id} disabled!<br>\n";
            $to_disable[] = $content_id;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "USER {$row['user_id']} should have the CONTENT {$content_id} enabled!<br>\n";
            $to_enable[] = $content_id;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}

if (sizeof($to_disable) > 0)
{
    $connector->query("UPDATE content 
                          SET active = 0
                        WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$to_disable).")");
}
echo "UPDATE content SET active = 0 WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$to_disable).")<br>\n";

if (sizeof($to_enable) > 0)
{
    $connector->query("UPDATE content 
                          SET active = 1
                        WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$to_enable).")");
}
echo "UPDATE content SET active = 0 WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$to_enable).")";
```

---

## Using your SQL dump this is what I get:

```
USER 9 currently have 15!
USER 9 after CONTENT 16 now have 10!
USER 9 after CONTENT 30 now have 5!
USER 9 after CONTENT 17 now have 4!
USER 9 after CONTENT 31 now have -1!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 31 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 18 now have -4!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 18 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 32 now have -9!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 32 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 20 now have -13!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 20 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 33 now have -18!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 33 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 21 now have -22!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 21 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 34 now have -26!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 34 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 22 now have -31!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 22 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 24 now have -36!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 24 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 26 now have -41!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 26 disabled!
USER 9 after CONTENT 29 now have -45!
USER 9 should have the CONTENT 29 disabled!

USER 10 after CONTENT 28 now have 95!

USER 11 after CONTENT 27 now have -4!
USER 11 should have the CONTENT 27 disabled!
```

And the `UPDATE` result:

```
UPDATE content SET active = 0 WHERE id IN (31,18,32,20,33,21,34,22,24,26,29,27)
```

And here is the sample code used to read the data as is:

```
<?php    
// Your database info
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

$con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT b.id AS user_id,
               b.monetos,
               GROUP_CONCAT(a.id ORDER BY a.id DESC) AS content_ids, 
               GROUP_CONCAT(a.cpc ORDER BY a.id DESC) AS cpc
          FROM content a
          JOIN users b 
            ON a.user = b.id
      GROUP BY b.id";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

if ($result->rowCount() == 0)
{
    die('No data found...');
}

$to_disable = array();
$to_enable = array();
foreach($result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
{
    $monetos = $row['monetos'];
    $data = array_combine(explode(',',$row['content_ids']), explode(',',$row['cpc']));
    echo "USER {$row['user_id']} currently have {$monetos}!<br>\n";
    foreach ($data as $content_id => $cpc)
    {
        $monetos -= $cpc;
        echo "USER {$row['user_id']} after CONTENT {$content_id} now have {$monetos}!<br>\n";
        if ($monetos <= 0)
        {
            echo "USER {$row['user_id']} should have the CONTENT {$content_id} disabled!<br>\n";
            $to_disable[] = $content_id;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "USER {$row['user_id']} should have the CONTENT {$content_id} enabled!<br>\n";
            $to_enable[] = $content_id;
        }
    }
    echo "<br>\n";
}

if (sizeof($to_disable) > 0)
{
    $ids = implode(',',$to_disable);
    $sql = "UPDATE content 
               SET active = 0
             WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
    $disable = $con->prepare($sql);
    $disable->execute();
    echo "UPDATE content SET active = 0 WHERE id IN ({$ids})<br>\n";
}
else
{
    echo "Nothing was disabled...<br>\n";
}

if (sizeof($to_enable) > 0)
{
    $ids = implode(',',$to_enable);
    $sql = "UPDATE content 
               SET active = 1
             WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
    $enable = $con->prepare($sql);
    $enable->execute();
    echo "UPDATE content SET active = 1 WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
}
else
{
    echo "Nothing was enabled...";
}
$con = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try two UPDATE statements?

```
UPDATE
  users u JOIN
  ( SELECT user, SUM(cpc) AS cpc FROM content GROUP BY user) as c ON (u.id=c.user)
SET u.monetos = u.monetos - c.cpc;
UPDATE content AS c
  SET c.active = 0
WHERE
  (SELECT u.monetos FROM users u WHERE c.user = u.id) <= 0;
```

I didn't get if users.monetos was allowed to go negative or not. If not you can add an IF() check to the SET u.monetos

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39fca/2)

Comment: He does not want to `SUM` the CPC's but rather go 1 by 1 and disable only once he runs out of credits.

Comment: @Prix, first let me thank you for your time. 
how can i see in your edit, user.monetos are updated, but don't want this. i just want to CHECK if a users.id have enought coins for all the entries in content. if so, nothing changes (even monetos, even cpc, even content.active). but if at one step i detected that monetos are out, the only thing that change is content.active. MONETOS amount, CONTENT cpc remains the same.

Comment: @dwellman, thank you for attention, check out please my comment above

Comment: Sounds to me you would investigate using a TRIGGER, then.